# Работа с датой время

Tags: php, datetime

В бд хранится дат время в таком формате 1486983600187. Как мне получить читабельный? PHP.

Comment: Уточните, получить *куда*, и какой формат вы считаете *читабельным*?

Comment: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1486983600);`

Comment: К сведению ретивых голосователей. Этот вопрос надо закрывать не как  "слишком общий", а как дубликат.

Comment: @Ипатьев Если Вы нашли тему-дубликат, укажите её, что ли. Тогда "ретивым голосователям" будет проще принять правильное, с Вашей точки зрения, решение...

Comment: @Akina 1. Нет, я не находил тему-дубликат. Я всего лишь предполагаю, что для столь банального вопроса она точно существует. 2. То, что "ретивых голосователей" не ткнули носом в дубликат, никак не является основанием для того чтобы называть самый что ни на есть конкретный вопрос "общим"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1486983600187` - это unix-like timestamp в миллисекундах, скорее всего получен из Javascript.

Для получения обычного unix-timestamp его нужно разделить на 1000;

Для получения из timestamp даты-времени в нужном формате существует функция [date](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

```
$time = 1486983600187;
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time / 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `DateTime::createFromFormat` и формат `U` [документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Либо средствами sql

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`), '%d-%m-%Y') as "date"
```

Comment: Судя по всему там не секунды а милисекунды, надо ещё на 1000 разделить.

Answer (score 1):

> В **бд** хранится дат время в таком формате 1486983600187.

Hадо было указать, в какой именно СУБД. Предполагаю, что это MySQL. В таком случае гораздо разумнее сразу от сервера получать дату-время, приведённые к нужному типу и отформатированные в нужный вид.

Кроме того, надо было указать тип поля, в котором хранится такое значение. Потому как 1486983600187 **для хранения в СУБД** ни под UNIXTIME, ни под TIMESTAMP не подходит (для первого слишком велико, а для второго слишком мало).

Если **vp_arth** прав, и это UNIXTIME, умноженный на 1000,

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME('1486983600187' / 1000) AS FormattedDateTime;
+----------------------------+
| FormattedDateTime          |
+----------------------------+
| 2017-02-13 14:00:00.187000 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($row['date]));
```